# UITabBar Controller and UITableView Controller - would one effect the other?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

Perhaps a simple or stupid question. I have tested three separate apps, each simple UITableViewController apps with detail view controllers pushed onto the stack. All work with no problems.

I've now decided to build a new app that uses a three tab UITabBar Controller as my rootviewcontroller and have these three separate tableViewControllers running off the tabBar controller. I can fire up my first level TableViews but I can't push their respective childViewControllers onto the stack. I'm using the same class code for each UITableViewController in the tabBar app as I tested in the tableView app.

Am I missing something obvious here? Why wouldn't this work because of a TabBar Controller?

Thanks for any insights in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closer at your three separate apps, you'll see they have the UITableViewControllers inside of UINavigationControllers. You probably left the navigation controllers out of your version with the UITabBarController.

The hierarchy should look something like this:

```
UITabBarController
 ┣ UINavigationController
 ┃  ┗ UITableViewController
 ┣ UINavigationController
 ┃  ┗ UITableViewController
 ┗ UINavigationController
    ┗ UITableViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this: create a new project based on the tab
   bar controller template, expand the tab and
   you'll see some UIViewControllers
   hanging there.  Now drag a
   "Navigation Controller" from the
   library and drop it under the tabs, you'll see it has a UIViewController
   as a child. Drop a "Table View Controller" on that child.

You'll see the structure proposed by Anomie (who is a fast typer :P ). This is a very typical structure for an iPhone app.

Comment: thanks for your help. i was a bit confused what you were trying to say here. i found this video online and I think it is what I'm looking for: http://www.youtube.com/user/smarkars#p/a/f/1/LBnPfAtswgw